# ASP.NET/C#: Retrieving listview value and passing to C# via a checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox, findcontrol

I've seen various solutions to this on here, but for some reason it isn't working for me. Basically on the client side I'm generating Listview elements from a database and want to retrieve the value generated in the "catlbl" label value and pass to C# to add to an "int total variable", which already has a value in it when the page is generated. Here is my ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="elecMod_listview" runat="server" DataSourceID="elecModule_sqlDataSource">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
             <td>
                <asp:Hyperlink ID="elecModuleDesc_hyperlink" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left" Text='<%# string.Concat(Eval("code"), " - ", Eval("name"))%>' NavigateURL='<%# "student_module_info.aspx?searchquery=" + Eval("code")%>' />
             </td>
             <td>
                 <asp:Label ID ="cat_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("catPoints") %>'></asp:Label>
             </td>
             <td>
                <asp:Label ID="semester_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("semesterNum") %>'></asp:Label>
             </td>
             <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="elective_checkbox" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left" OnCheckedChanged="elective_checkbox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
             </td>
           </tr>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here is my label code:

```
<div class="row mt">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      Total CAT Points Selected: <asp:Label ID="catTotal_lbl" runat="server" Text="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

And now here is my C# code:

```
//This value will be changed upon Page Load via other parts in the code and is displayed in the "catTotal_lbl" 
int total = 0; 
protected void elective_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewDataItem row in elecMod_listview.Items)
    {
        CheckBox catCheck = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("elective_checkbox");
        if(catCheck.Checked)
        {
            int elecCat = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("cat_lbl")).Text);

            total += elecCat;
        }
    }

}
```

When I check the box, nothing happens. I basically want the value from "catPoints" added to the "catTotal_lbl" whenever I check the checkbox(s) and then stick that value in a database via C#. Been racking my brains on this for awhile! I'm still a newb so apologies if I broke any protocol.

**EDIT:** 
I was able to make it work by adding this to the C#:

```
 protected void elective_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (ListViewDataItem row in elecMod_listview.Items)
    {
        CheckBox catCheck = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("elective_checkbox");
        if(catCheck.Checked)
        {
            int elecCat = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("cat_lbl")).Text);

            total += elecCat;
            catTotal_lbl.Text = total.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

But I would like to update the catTotal_lbl Label upon checking the checkbox in an UpdatePanel in AJAX. *Is this feasible?* Basically when I check the checkbox now, it reloads the whole page but it DOES change the label to the correct amount of CAT points now. I don't want it to reload the entire page, though.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Have you tried debugging the method elective_checkbox_CheckedChanged to see if you are getting the value in "elecCat" variable? If you want to show the value in the label you need to assign the value to lablel

Comment: Sorry, I should have expanded on that, By nothing happening, I mean that the total in the catTotal_lbl isn't changing. I want to be able to click on the corresponding checkbox and add the value of "catPoints" to the "catTotal_lbl". "catTotal_lbl" is being generated by "int total" already in other parts of the code so basically I want the value from "catPoints" to be added to what's already in "int total",

Also when I tried debugging it, it's not breaking when I check the checkbox.